# Can the variables of a function represent multiple values at the same time?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I am writing a trigonometry section for a pre-calculus course and have drawn the unit circle diagrams shown.  In the left version, I've used distinct variables to represent each point.  I like the clarity this provides students, but am wondering if this is necessary.  I know the point of a variable is to represent multiple values at once, but when I used this idea to draw the second diagram, I feel like I've defined the variables twice.  Is my second diagram a reasonable representation?

[image]

Comment: Just like the variable "x" could have two different values on two different pages of a book, or in two different problems, so too can this happen, for instance, in two neighboring sentences, or two parts of same diagram. The color-coding in your picture, in my opinion, makes it almost impossible for someone to misunderstand that particular detail, so it's really completely a matter of preference.

Comment: To be pedantic: *no* the same "variable" can never have two different values simultaneously, but you're free to use the same *letter* or *symbol* to represent several *different* variables (which do have different values) as long as your careful and make this clear, which you have done in my opinion. (Your two thetas are not "the same variable," they're two different ones, in different sentences, with the same name, and there' s no confusion since you never need to use them both at once.)